# How to assign coordinates (x,y) to an Array and calculate distance between them? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, coordinates, distance

I am new to Java.

How do I assign a list of items with coordinates e.g. (x,y) to an Array and to calculate the distance between each of them?

Grateful if anyone could help!

Comment: Before you submitted your question, did you ask yourself *Did I provide enough information? Will people be able to understand my question? **Is my question far too vague?***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What have you tried?  You'll do better here if you actually post code that you've written and show some effort.

Start with a `Point`:

```
public class Point {
    private final double x;
    private final double y;

    public Point(x, y) { 
        this.x = x; 
        this.y = y;
    }

    public static double distance(Point a, Point b) {
        double dx = a.x - b.x;
        double dy = a.y - b.y;
        return Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `java.awt.Point`? There is even a method called `distanceSq(double, double)`

Comment: "new to Java" - that's the key, IMO.